# bytecode and ASM

Tags: java, bytecode, descriptor

[Here](https://www.vmth.ucdavis.edu/incoming/Jasmin/ref--33.html) is a reference about the INVOKESPECIAL bytecode instruction. If I have an AbstractInsnNode from the ASM framework containing the INVOKESPECIAL instruction,will my node  include the method specification of the instruction? 
For example, with a code like this:

```
String ins = insn.toString;
```

If the insn had a INVOKESPECIAL instruction, my ins would have a string like "invokespecial java/lang/StringBuffer/()V"?

What I want to do is get the method specification from a INVOKESPECIAL instruction and store it in a string so my program can read it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to read class at runtime? try this

```
    import org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader;
    import org.objectweb.asm.util.ASMifierClassVisitor;


    ClassReader cr = new ClassReader(b);
    cr.accept(new ASMifierClassVisitor(new PrintWriter(System.out)), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

> If I have an AbstractInsnNode from the ASM framework containing the INVOKESPECIAL instruction,will my node include the method specification of the instruction?

AFAIK, yes.  It should be an instance of [`MethodInsnNode`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm30/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/tree/MethodInsnNode.html) and the `desc` field should be a method descriptor string.

> If the insn had a INVOKESPECIAL instruction, my ins would have a string like "invokespecial java/lang/StringBuffer/()V"?

Actually, there are three components.  The method descriptor string, the method name and the internal name of the class that owns the (in this case, actual) method.

Comment: so if I convert a methodinsnnode variable to string I will be able to use a method like .contains("lang") to find the word "lang" in the descriptor?

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea.  You should be able to cast the object to `MethodInsnNode` then access the information via the declared fields.  It is a little unclear what information you are actually after, but it *looks like* you want the name of the type that declares the method rather than the method's signature.  (Unfortunately, there are aspects of your Question that make no sense.)

Comment: Let me try to explain: I just want to store in a string the descriptor (where is the name of the superclass invoked by the invokespecial instruction) so my program could eventually read this string and know if the method was called to handle a exception